# Show that $|e^z -1| \leq e^{|z|}-1$ for any z

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $|e^z -1| \leq e^{|z|}-1$

What i have tried is

Let $z=x+iy$.Then,
$$|e^z-1|=|e^x\cos y-1+ie^x\sin y|=\sqrt{(e^x\cos y-1)^2+(e^x \sin y)^2}=\sqrt{e^{2x}-2e^x\cos y+1}$$

I stuck here and no idea how to continue with it.
Or is there any other approach to prove it?

Comment: That must be wrong. The rhs is *negative* for $z = -1$.

Comment: It's easy if you use the power series of the exponential.

Comment: @MartinR do you mean that there is mistake with the question?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat i haven't learnt power series yet. Is there any identity about exponential that can be used here?

Comment: @MartinR No, $e^{|-1|}-1=e-1>0$.

Comment: Oops, my stupid mistake - sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest approach:

$$|e^z-1|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}\right|\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|z|^k}{k!} = e^{|z|}-1$$

Alternatively, use:

$$e^z=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^n$$

And show that $$\left|\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^n-1\right|\leq \left(1+\frac{|z|}{n}\right)^n-1$$

Answer (score 1):

It just follows from the fact that $f(z)=e^{z}-1$ is a holomorphic (entire) function, hence by the [maximum modulus principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) we have that
$$ \max_{|z|\leq R}|f(z)| $$
is attained in a point $z_0$ for which $|z_0|=R$ and for any $R>0$ the function $g:[-\pi,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}^+$ given by:
$$ g(\theta) = \left|\exp\left(Re^{i\theta}\right)-1\right|^2 = e^{2R\cos\theta}-2e^{R\cos\theta}\cos(R\sin\theta)+1 $$
is very well-behaved (gaussian-shaped) and attains its maximum for $\theta=0$.

Beside that, I agree that Thomas Andrews' approach is way easier.