# Proof for $|e^z-1| \leq e^{|z|}-1 \leq |z|e^{|z|}$ and $|e^z| = e^{Re(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, exponential-function, eulers-number-e

Prove that

$$|e^z-1| \leq e^{|z|}-1 \leq |z|e^{|z|}$$ and $$|e^z| = e^{Re(z)}$$

For the inequation $|e^z-1| \leq e^{|z|}-1$, I was thinking that if $z<0$ the left part would be smaller than the right part and if $z>0$ it would be equal.

Comment: $z$ is a complex number so saying $z<0$ and $z>0$ is erroneous.

Comment: Hint: Use the power series definition of the exponential function to prove the inequalities. To prove the equality, decompose $z$ into real and imaginary parts and use $e^{a+b}=e^a e^b$.

Comment: For the first estimate, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260485/show-that-ez-1-leq-ez-1-for-any-z or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488241/proving-the-inequality-ez-1-leq-ez-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint

$$|e^z-1|=\left|\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{z^n}{n!}\right|\leq \sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{|z|^n}{n!}
$$

If $z=x+iy$
$e^{z}=e^{x}e^{iy}$ and $|e^{iy}|=1$

For the las inequality, it suffices to assume $z$ is a nonnegative number, that is  show $e^t-1\leq te^t$ for all $t\geq0$.  The  mean value theorem may be useful.

Comment: It is simply the triangle inequality, no mean value theorem required